Question about practical design for OOB Management network
I checked the following documents from Dell about the design/implementation of the OOB Management network and have the question below in my mind. Please kindly help me explain and clarify it.
https://infohub.delltechnologies.com/en-us/l/dell-technologies-enterprise-sonic-for-powerflex-deployment-guide/oob-management-topology-30/
https://infohub.delltechnologies.com/en-us/l/dell-technologies-enterprise-sonic-for-powerflex-deployment-guide/oob-management-connection-details-30/
I don't see any connection to the OOB port of the N3248TE-ON and the switches in the OOB Core. How I can manage these switches in the OOB fashion. In another way, how do we manage the OOB network itself.
Thanks a lot.

Depending on the complexity of the production network, one way to handle OOB network management is to make the OOB network flat and not in need of any management.


I don't see any connection to the OOB port of the N3248TE-ON and the switches in the OOB Core.

That's because for the N3248TE-ON the OoB connections to the other switches are just LAN connections.
An OoB port is a dedicated port for management only. If you'd connect them to each other the switches' management planes could talk to each other (with little purpose) but nothing else. Instead, you connect each OoB port to your OoB network (see below).

How I can manage these switches in the OOB fashion.

You use the OoB network to manage the switches normally.

In another way, how do we manage the OOB network itself.

If you use dedicated management switches then you connect their OoB ports to that network, too, or you manage them in-band.
An OoB (or any managment) network is special in that routing and access is tightly controlled. Since management is sensitive you only allow specific end nodes to interact with the network.
At the very least you should have a dedicated VLAN for management. Depending on your security or resilience requirements you could have a dedicated physical infrastructure as well.
